# Что значит " in c++ 98 "?

Tags: c++

Вот у меня есть такой код.

[image: Вот у меня есть такой код.]

Но как исправить эту ошибку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Изменить в настройках проекта используемый стандарт С++.

Comment: В 1998 году был опубликован стандарт языка ISO/IEC 14882:1998 (известный как C++98). https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: а почему вы просто ```=``` не уберете, вы не проинциализирвоали ваш вектор, а пытаетесь его присвоить к чему-то

Comment: @AyratArifullin не поможет - будет синтаксическая ошибка до С++11, так как в данном случае как раз и происходит инициализация вектора - вызывается конструктор с `std::initializer_list<int>` (в С++11 и выше), но в стандарте языка до С++11 ни его, ни braced-инициализации попросту не было. Присваивания тут в коде и в помине нет - надо понимать разницу между присваиванием и инициализацией.

Answer (score 0):

Инициализация вектора таким вот образом была введена только в стандарте С++11.

```cpp
std::vector<int> myVector = { 8, 9 };
```

Вы же используете старый стандарт в настройках компилятора - т.е. стандарт С++98, где такое ещё незаконно.

Решений два:
1) Сменить стандарт языка в опциях компилятора на более новый
2) Если принципиально использование С++98, то вот так вот надо:

```cpp
std::vector<int> myVector;
myVector.reserve( 2 ); // по-хорошему надо 9, так как дальше ещё есть push_back
                       // нужно это для того, чтобы в push_back память не выделялась
myVector.push_back( 8 );
myVector.push_back( 9 );
```